# Do the Python objects — functions, modules, class, etc. — also store their names in the object?

Tags: python, function, class, object, import

Do the Python objects — *functions, modules, class, etc.* — also store their names in the object? Suppose if `import math` is executed, then a module object is created. Does this module object also contain its name `math` as its data?

Comment: `math.__name__` and `math.__file__`

Comment: @Peter Wood Hey, one question. Let's say if I write ```import math; print(math)```, the output is ```<module 'math' from...>```. Is this string searched from the ```sys.modules``` dictionary when I write ```print(math)```?

Comment: I don't know what the implementation is, but it's almost certainly the string representation of the module object. So that is how a module object represents itself, nothing to do with pulling a name from the `sys.modules` dictionary.

Comment: @Peter Wood What do you mean by *"string representation of the module object."*?

Comment: Look up documentation about `__repr__`

Comment: @Peter Wood I did ```print(repr(math))``` and got the same output. Does python converts ```print(math)``` to ```print(repr(math))```?

Comment: Search for “python how does print convert objects”. I’m guessing that will give you useful results.

Comment: @Peter Wood Last question: Which objects do not contain the ```__name__``` attribute?

Comment: I don’t know. By deciding to only ask me you’re cutting down your chances of getting a good answer. There are thousands of people on Stack Overflow. Search first then ask a good clear question if you still don’t know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding modules: they have `__name__` attribute consider following examples

*simple import*

```
import math
print(math.__name__)
```

Output:

```
math
```

*import as...*

```
import math as something
print(something.__name__)
```

Output

```
math
```

Comment: Hey, one question. Let's say if I write ```import math; print(math)```, the output is ```<module 'math' from...>```. Is this string searched from the ```sys.modules``` dictionary when I write ```print(math)```?